# When to use jade templating?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, template-engine

Found Jade templating interesting. However, currently I'm unable to imagine under which scenario jade would be used or where to apply jade templating. Can anyone give me a practical scenario/example where the power of jade templating is leveraged.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine you have an application computing some values server-side, for example a list of rooms in a chat.

Then you have 2 reasonable solutions :

1. send those data as JSON in order for some JavaScript client side to build the list
2. generate the list in HTML server side

A templating system is useful for this second solution.

To generate this HTML, instead of having your nodejs program concatenate pieces of HTML, a templating engine is a good solution.

The JS part of the server would generate the data (here using express and fetching the data from a relational database) :

```
app.get('/rooms', ensureAuthenticated, ensureCompleteProfile, function(req, res){
        db.on(req.user.id)
        .then(function(uid){
                return [
                        this.listAccessibleRooms(uid),
                        this.fetchUserPingRooms(uid, 0)
                ]
        }).spread(function(accessibleRooms, pings){
                var rooms = {public:[], private:[]};
                accessibleRooms.forEach(function(r) {
                        r.path = roomPath(r);
                        rooms[r.private?'private':'public'].push(r);
                });
                res.render('rooms.jade', { rooms:rooms, pings:pings });
        }).finally(db.off);
});
```

and the Jade file would use them :

```
table.list
        each room, i in rooms.public
                tr
                        th: a(href=room.path) #{room.name}
                        td.rendered #{room.description}
                        if room.auth
                                td.role= room.auth
```

which generates this kind of HTML :

```
<table class="list">
    <tr>
        <th><a href="path1">Room 1</a></th>
        <td class="rendered">Description of room 1</td>
        <td class="role">Admin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><a href="path2">Room 2</a></th>
        <td class="rendered">Description of room 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This separates a little the concerns that are managing the data and displaying them. It also has the advantage of not being too different from HTML which, in my opinion, is good when the goal is to generate HTML.

This example is taken from [my open source Miaou chat](http://dystroy.org/miaou). The complete Jade file is [rooms.jade](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/views/rooms.jade).

Comment: @destroy, thanks for the info. Looks like a good learning curve NodeJS  + Express + Jade :)

Comment: In my personal opinion a complex application would use both solution : send some data as json (in ajax, or using websocket) or generate static HTML using Jade. I also sometimes use Jade to embed JSON in the page in a kind of mixed approach when I need the data to be also handled in JS client side : https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/views/login.jade#L20

Comment: dystroy, jade can be used on the client-side as well as on the server side, so you can send data as json to the client and render html there to insert it. Jade fits in both cases well.

Comment: @alex Yes it can (to others readers : you may use something like https://github.com/domenic/jadeify that I never used) but I'm not sure it's a full general solution as usually, if you want to build elements of your page client side, it's because you have something more complex than what Jade can easily provide.

Comment: People usually want to build elements on the client-side for just one reason: they want to update the page without reloading it. It can be done easily with jade, and I'm convinced that it fits as a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Templating engines can also be used

**Server side MVC frameworks**
Pretty much like the Express example Denys provided.
ex: [ASP.NET MVC's Razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c), [Laravel's Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#introduction), ...

**Static website generators**
Generate a static site from dynamic content (json, a db, ...). Useful if you cannot use a server side language or don't want to pay for it.
ex: [Jekyll's Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/), ...

**An invoicing app**
A templating engine creates html which is then transformed into a [pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf). Or any other application that produces pdfs.